# Unable to run vbscript file on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

When I try to run a `.vbs` file on my *Windows 10* laptop it shows the following error.

[image]

Comment: How did you try to run the file? Obviously there is a file a.vbs on the (?your?) Desktop.

Comment: Make sure cscript.exe and wscript.exe present in System32 and/or in SysWOW64 folder.

Comment: Can you post the source code of this vbscript ?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons this might happen:

1. The script is downloaded from the internet, so it is blocked. Unblock it via properties on the file.
2. You have some sort of anti-malware installed that blocks access to the file. Check your logs for any information.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Based on comment from Peter (thank you for that), I edit my answer.

You probably either rights issue - you don't have rights to execute your script on your desktop or you maybe the scripting is blocked altogether?  More information is needed from you - what kind of script is that?  The best would be to provide the source code + what are the rights on the directory (or directory chain) where you try to execute your code.

This is in case you need to elevate the rights of your script which is not yet your case:

You have to have privileges to run your script.  You can either start your command prompt as Administrator

Or

use `runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator your_script.vbs` from your user command line

Or

Finally you can add UAC directly to your script:

This is source code from Microsoft technet:

```
'---------------------------------------
'Elevate this script before invoking it.
'25.2.2011 FNL
'---------------------------------------
bElevate = False
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then If WScript.Arguments(WScript.Arguments.Count-1) <> "|" then bElevate = True
if bElevate Or WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then ElevateUAC
'******************
'Your script goes here
'******************


'-----------------------------------------
'Run this script under elevated privileges
'-----------------------------------------
Sub ElevateUAC
    sParms = " |"
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
            For i = WScript.Arguments.Count-1 To 0 Step -1
            sParms = " " & WScript.Arguments(i) & sParms
        Next
    End If
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", WScript.ScriptFullName & sParms, , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have to be an administrator to run a vbs script, and the message would be very different. There may be certain things in the script that you can only perform in elevated mode, but at least the script would executing in the first place.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: you are right about the message would be different. Maybe user restriction?  Nothing can be executed from desktop? The originator - could you try to run it from e.g. c:\test (make that directory yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file is on the "Public Desktop". If it is, it will appear
on every user's visual "desktop", but Windows will fail to find it in the
user Desktop folders.